# $(...).modal() is not a function nuxt js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, nuxt.js

I'm trying to toggle a modal in a vue component based on a route change.
When calling $("#loginModal").modal("show"); nuxt shows that .modal is not a function.

I have imported jQuery and bootstrap.js in the nuxt.config.js file, and in the correct order.

I have tried referencing the bootstrap.js file from within the node_modules folder and from a CDN, so I'm sure it's not an error in including the lib.

Modal component

```js
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Test modal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {return {

        }}, 
        watch: {
            $route (to, from) {
                if (to.query.modal == "login") {
                    $("#loginModal").modal("show");
                } else {
                    $('#loginModal').modal("hide");
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || 'website name ;)',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      {
        src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      },

      {
        src: "https://kit.fontawesome.com/a772a37d1d.js", 
        type: "text/javascript"
      },

      {
        src: "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js", 
        type: "text/javascript" 
      }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/main.css"
  ],
 
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // "@nuxtjs/dotenv",
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you shoudlnt really use jquery with nuxt. use vue-bootstrap instead

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check the below link for this issue 
https://codesandbox.io/s/733xo5v390